# На jQuery по клику удалить часть строки <li>

Tags: jquery, input

Есть выпадающий список ul li, который появляется при клике по полю инпута. До клика ul li не существует на странице. Как с помощью jQuery при клике на элемент из списка сделать добавление в инпут только части строки?
Суть: в выпадающем списке товар+цена, цена для удобства, но она в инпут попадать не должна. Между наименованием и ценой разделитель "|".

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-name">Наименование:</label>
  <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="" id="input-name" class="form-control">
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li data-value="4296"><a href="#"> Батарейка | Цена 0.1200</a></li>
  <li data-value="4245"><a href="#"> Батарейка2 | Цена 0.7000</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Прошу прощения у людей, что дали ответ ранее, от незнания основ не учел момент с появлением списка ul li только при клике в поле инпут.

Нашел, где сидит автодополнение, интуитивно пониманию, что нужно вставить код в конец, где $dropdown.on('click', '> li > a', $.proxy(this.click, this)); но не могу понять как это сделать правильно.

```js
// Autocomplete */
(function($) {
 $.fn.autocomplete = function(option) {
  return this.each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var $dropdown = $('<ul class="dropdown-menu" />');
   
   this.timer = null;
   this.items = [];

   $.extend(this, option);

   $this.attr('autocomplete', 'off');

   // Focus
   $this.on('focus', function() {
    this.request();
   });

   // Blur
   $this.on('blur', function() {
    setTimeout(function(object) {
     object.hide();
    }, 200, this);
   });

   // Keydown
   $this.on('keydown', function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
     case 27: // escape
      this.hide();
      break;
     default:
      this.request();
      break;
    }
   });

   // Click
   this.click = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var value = $(event.target).parent().attr('data-value');

    if (value && this.items[value]) {
     this.select(this.items[value]);
    }
   }

   // Show
   this.show = function() {
    var pos = $this.position();

    $dropdown.css({
     top: pos.top + $this.outerHeight(),
     left: pos.left
    });

    $dropdown.show();
   }

   // Hide
   this.hide = function() {
    $dropdown.hide();
   }

   // Request
   this.request = function() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);

    this.timer = setTimeout(function(object) {
     object.source($(object).val(), $.proxy(object.response, object));
    }, 200, this);
   }

   // Response
   this.response = function(json) {
    var html = '';
    var category = {};
    var name;
    var i = 0, j = 0;

    if (json.length) {
     for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      // update element items
      this.items[json[i]['value']] = json[i];

      if (!json[i]['category']) {
       // ungrouped items
       html += '<li data-value="' + json[i]['value'] + '"><a href="#">' + json[i]['label'] + '</a></li>';
      } else {
       // grouped items
       name = json[i]['category'];
       if (!category[name]) {
        category[name] = [];
       }

       category[name].push(json[i]);
      }
     }

     for (name in category) {
      html += '<li class="dropdown-header">' + name + '</li>';

      for (j = 0; j < category[name].length; j++) {
       html += '<li data-value="' + category[name][j]['value'] + '"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + category[name][j]['label'] + '</a></li>';
      }
     }
    }

    if (html) {
     this.show();
    } else {
     this.hide();
    }

    $dropdown.html(html);
   }

   $dropdown.on('click', '> li > a', $.proxy(this.click, this));
   $this.after($dropdown);
  });
 }
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: вот пример верстки с различными вариантами и приведите.

Comment: Уточните, что Вы имеете ввиду под "Между наименованием и ценой может быть любой разделитель"? По идее разделитель должен быть такой, какой не встречается в имени товара...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у Вас во время выполнения кода/добавления обработчика события HTML элементы не присутствуют в документе, то можно отслеживать все события `click` и отфильтровывать затем только те, которые удовлетворяют фильтру:

```js
var sep = "|";
$(document).on("click", "a.product-label", function() {
  var str = this.innerHTML;
  $("#input-name").val(str.substr(0, str.indexOf(sep)).trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="input-name">Наименование:</label>
  <input type="text" id="input-name" value="" />
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="product-label"> Батарейка | Цена 0.1200</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="product-label"> Батарейка2 | Цена 0.7000</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="product-label"> Атомная батарея | Цена 999.000</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает, не понимаю почему, может быть из-за того, что ul li не существует до клика по инпуту?

Comment: @Андрей а при чём клик по инпуту? Вы же в вопросе указали что клик на li? Если у Вас элемент ul не существует в момент выполнения приведённого кода, то нужно использовать другой подход.

Comment: Это я от незнания. ul li появляется в момент клика по полю инпута.

Comment: @Андрей поправил ответ.

Comment: идеально, я бы Вас расцеловал)) Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Андрей Вы другой ответ "расцеловали" :)

Comment: Эта форма тоже задачка в своем роде, теперь правильно еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Подойдет обычный `split('|')` с последующим `shift()` и `trim()`:

```js
$("ul > li a").on("click", function() {
  $("#input-name").val(this.innerHTML.split('|').shift().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="input-name">Наименование:</label>
  <input type="text" id="input-name" value="" />
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li data-value="4296"><a href="#"> Батарейка | Цена 0.1200</a></li>
    <li data-value="4245"><a href="#"> Батарейка2 | Цена 0.7000</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Если название товара будет содержать дефис, то код отработает некорректно обрезав часть названия. Скорее всего нужно заранее определять разделитель...

Comment: так точно, однако Автор это не указал

Comment: Я запутанно выразился, разделитель будет такой, какой проще фильтровать, например "|". Его в товарах точно не будет.

Comment: @Андрей тогда и без регулярок